# You need to ensure that you can integrate WebApp1 with GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

•   Name: WebApp1
•   Publish: Code
•   Runtime stack: Java 11
•   Operating system: Linux
•   Continuous deployment: Disable
You need to ensure that you can integrate WebApp1 with GitHub Actions.
Which setting should you modify?